# Installed Google Earth now can't open Skype

Tags: skype, google-earth

I installed Google Earth as per [this walkthrough](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10583845) and now I can't open or use Skype.

I had to use a sudo prefix on some of the steps to edit files and do things without "permission denied" errors.

I desperately need Skype back. Any thoughts on what went wrong or how to uninstall Google Earth and fix my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only step that looks like can cause a problem in that walk-through is the dynamic linker configuration changes. I'd try this steps:

- Delete the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/googleearth.conf` file.
- run, as root, `ldconfig` again.

You can use the following commands to do it:

```
sudo rm /etc/ld.so.conf.d/googleearth.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

I have not tested it, but it can be easily reversed following those two points in the tutorial again. Hope this helps.

Comment: This solved my issue - thanks so much for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

From one (relative) n00b to another, the quickest way to fix this is probably to reinstall skype. My guess is that the google earth install messed with some shared component.

After I installed adobe air google chrome would no longer play flash. I reinstalled chrome (or maybe just flash, can't remember) and that fixed the problem.